# Resizing ttk.frame of a ttk notebook, frame defined in a other class than the notebook

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I have a main class for my gui and I added a ttk.NoteBook after a label:

```
class MainApplication(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.geometry('1000x500')
        self.configure(background='#F0F8FF')

        #TOP LABEL

        load = Image.open("my_image")
        load = load.resize((200, 67), Image.ANTIALIAS)
        self.render = ImageTk.PhotoImage(load)

        self.Label_top = tk.Label(self, image=self.render, compound=tk.LEFT, text="TOOL")
        self.Label_top.pack()


        #--Notebook---------

        self.notebook = ttk.Notebook(self)

        self.Page1 = Page1(self.notebook)
        self.Page2 = Page2(self.notebook)
        self.Page3 = Page3(self.notebook)
        self.Page4 = Page4(self.notebook)

        self.notebook.add(self.Page1, text='PAGE1')
        self.notebook.add(self.Page2, text='PAGE2')
        self.notebook.add(self.Page3, text='PAGE3')
        self.notebook.add(self.Page4, text='PAGE4')



        self.notebook.pack(fill='x', side=TOP)
        #expand=True create empty space between my top label          and my notebook, even with side=TOP
```

And I defined each frame in a class like this :

```
class Page1(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, container):
        super().__init__()

        self.(width=400, height=280) #Error message

        self.pack(expand=True) #Doesn't work
```

Do you know how can I expand my frame for that it fills my page and pack the notebook just after my top label

Comment: You don't need to call any layout function inside `Page1.__init__()`.  When a frame is added to a `Notebook`, it will fill the `Notebook`.  However, you need to change `self.notebook.pack(fill='x', side=TOP)` to `self.notebook.pack(fill='both', expand=1)` to make the notebook fill the window.

Comment: I tried this but when i did that, it created a empty space between my notebook and my top label.

Comment: There is no *top label* in your code.

Comment: When I run the code, I don't have any *empty space* between the image in the top label and the notebook.  Better post what you get currently and what you expect.

Comment: thanks you for your try. I will look if its not because of my notebook theme.

Comment: Did you change `fill='x'` to `fill='both'`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will do what you want. I've incorporated most of the things @Bryan Oakley mentioned in his answer except I also added a `BasePage` class and derived all the other `Page` classes from it. This was done to provide a place to put code that would otherwise need to be repeated each of the subclasses.

I also changed some of your variable names to conform to [PEP 8 Naming Conventions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#naming-conventions).

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
from tkinter.constants import *


class BasePage(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, container):
        super().__init__(container, width=400, height=280)
        classname = type(self).__name__
        tk.Label(self, text=f'Welcome to {classname}').place(relx=0.5, rely=0.25, 
                                                             anchor=CENTER)

class Page1(BasePage):
    def __init__(self, container):
        super().__init__(container)

class Page2(BasePage):
    def __init__(self, container):
        super().__init__(container)

class Page3(BasePage):
    def __init__(self, container):
        super().__init__(container)

class Page4(BasePage):
    def __init__(self, container):
        super().__init__(container)


class MainApplication(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.geometry('1000x500')
        self.configure(background='#F0F8FF')

        #--Notebook---------

        self.notebook = ttk.Notebook(self)

        self.page1 = Page1(self.notebook)
        self.page2 = Page2(self.notebook)
        self.page3 = Page3(self.notebook)
        self.page4 = Page4(self.notebook)

        self.notebook.add(self.page1, text='Page1')
        self.notebook.add(self.page2, text='Page2')
        self.notebook.add(self.page3, text='Page3')
        self.notebook.add(self.page4, text='Page4')

        self.notebook.pack(expand=True, fill=BOTH)


app = MainApplication()
app.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

I see three problems.

First, each "page" needs to be a child of the notebook. You do that by making sure the notebook is passed to the `__init__` of the frame:

```
class Page1(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, container):
        super().__init__(container)
```

Second, you need to *not* call `pack` on the page. `self.notebook.add` is already adding the frame to the notebook. So, remove the line `self.pack(expand=True)` from each page.

Third, `self.(width=400, height=280)` needs to be `self.configure(width=400, height=280)`